# Vault login issue using Boto3 SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, vault

```
import boto3
import hvac

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
print("access_key",credentials.access_key)
print("secret_key",credentials.secret_key)
print("token",credentials.token)
client = hvac.Client(url='https://vault.xxxxxxx/ui/vault/secrets/secret/show/appname/snowflake')
res=client.auth.aws.iam_login(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, credentials.token)
```

I am trying to authnticate vault using above code I can able to get accesskey,secrete key and token, but when i try to auth using this method **client.auth.aws.iam_login** getting below error

**TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable**

below is the stacktrace

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [272], in <cell line: 10>()
      8 print("token",credentials.token)
      9 client = hvac.Client(url='https://xxxxxxxx/ui/vault')
---> 10 res=client.auth.aws.iam_login(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, credentials.token)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hvac\api\auth_methods\aws.py:766, in Aws.iam_login(self, access_key, secret_key, session_token, header_value, role, use_token, region, mount_point)
    757 headers = json.dumps({k: [request.headers[k]] for k in request.headers})
    758 params = {
    759     "iam_http_request_method": request.method,
    760     "iam_request_url": b64encode(request.url.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8"),
   (...)
    763     "role": role,
    764 }
--> 766 return self._adapter.login(
    767     url=api_path,
    768     use_token=use_token,
    769     json=params,
    770 )

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hvac\adapters.py:199, in Adapter.login(self, url, use_token, **kwargs)
    196 response = self.post(url, **kwargs)
    198 if use_token:
--> 199     self.token = self.get_login_token(response)
    201 return response

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hvac\adapters.py:344, in JSONAdapter.get_login_token(self, response)
    336 def get_login_token(self, response):
    337     """Extracts the client token from a login response.
    338 
    339     :param response: The response object returned by the login method.
   (...)
    342     :rtype: str
    343     """
--> 344     return response["auth"]["client_token"]

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: updated full stack trace

Comment: There are a few potential issues here, but the immediate issue is that your Vault HVAC binding method is returning something other than a map/dictionary/json response from Vault when using the AWS authentication engine with IAM. I would try to reproduce this with the Vault CLI/API and observe the error, and then fix it in the code. I would speculate the AWS authentication engine is not configured correctly in the Vault cluster.

Answer (score 0):

it's difficult to reproduce the error without vault setup, and difficult to diagnose without the full stack trace...

### potential hvac  issues

- here are the [docs with examples](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/auth_methods/aws.html#iam-authentication). it looks some examples declare the class without args `hvac.Client()` and [others](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96323/hvac.Client) with url and token `hvac.Client(url=url, token=token)`

### potential boto3 issues

> [TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable in Python](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-response-object-is-not-subscriptable)

since `get_credentials()` returns a class you may need to parse the response with `res.json()` before the properties can be accessed

good luck!

### edit

looking at the full stack trace it looks like your adaptor.post isn't returning and expected response

```py
        return self._adapter.post(
            url=api_auth,
            json=params,
        )
```

try running the [configure method](https://github.com/hvac/hvac/blob/d25c8dabb74d568a1348ad8ec841abaacf7bb73a/hvac/api/auth_methods/aws.py#L21) and displaying the results, that should tell you more

something like:

```py
res=client.auth.aws.configure(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, credentials.token)
```

Comment: My aws creds and vault creds are not same.
i want to connect vault from my aws airflow, Everytime i can't use static vault token or my creds to connect from vault from airflow, that's why Iam trying to do in this way.

Comment: ah I see, removed that line from the post